# Overhead of using source control to sync heavy media folders

Tags: svn, version-control, distribution

I was thinking about using an existing remotely connected svn repositories infrastructure as a method to also sync media folders.

By media I mean about 1Tb of video content.

Is there any disadvantage by doing it using SVN?

Is the transfer protocol efficient to transfer big files?

Is there an overhead in storage?

Thanks

Comment: SVN is not a syncing solution. It's a source control solution. If you need syncing, use a syncing tool.

Comment: The idea is maybe to use it as syncing tool and also gain some nice to have version control along the way.

Comment: The whole question is to wonder if such a use makes a little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, SVN is about source-control.
It's not a syncying tool, even if you may also use it for that purpose.

That said, SVN works well with binary files (like your media files).
Of course, you can't get a diff on binary files, but it's quite OK for the storage.

As the SVN manual states:

> Note that whether or not a file is binary does not affect the amount
>   of repository space used to store changes to that file, nor does it
>   affect the amount of traffic between client and server. For storage
>   and transmission purposes, Subversion uses a diffing method that works
>   equally well on binary and text files; this is completely unrelated to
>   the diffing method used by the 'svn diff' command.

But remember that, if you only need syncing, you may have better options than SVN.
So try to take a look at other solutions, like [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) for instance, before deciding to use SVN.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly answers my question.

Comment: > **but it's quite OK for the storage**

are you kidding? svn stores every damn revision of binary file. it means that after two commits svn repository will be irreversibly swollen. it will do without commits though.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you do not use Subversion (or any version control system designed for source code) for doing this.  Subversion can handle binary files, but you don't get the merge, diff, etc. capabilities that are the main reason for using something like Subversion.  Technically, it would most likely work; however, there are much better tools for the job.

If all you are doing is synchronizing folders, try something like [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Something like [AlienBrain](http://www.alienbrain.com/) could give you versioning capabilities, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

## There is substantial overhead on the subversion client side.

The main problem for using subversion for large media files is that the standard client stores "pristine" copies of your files in the local workspace, thus effectively doubling the size of a checked-out copy of your library.  This is a conscious choice on the designers parts that is good for the standard subversion use case of source control but not optimal for large binary files.  At one point there were alternate clients that do not have this problem -- I haven't looked lately.

## There is often overhead/inefficiencies on the subversion server side.

A secondary problem is that if you store compressed binary files, a small change in the file content will produce an *entirely* different compression result, rendering subversions delta storage strategy useless.  Note that MP3 and many video formats *are* compressed, but that compression happens on blocks.  So while you see this problem in action -- a small change will affect the entire block -- it will not necessarily affect the entire file.

## Assumptions in SCM tools

I don't agree that SCM tools are necessarily bad choices for what you're trying to do, but most of them are not designed with this in mind and therefore have problems.  For my media requirements the workflow is a lot closer to an SCM tool than a sync tool such as rsync, unison or the like. However, some of the fundamental assumptions in SCM don't work well for large files.

If you have a workflow that creates a lot of changes to the files you'll probably want  to purge old version of your data fairly aggressively.  Most SCM tools are designed with the ideas that old data is *extremely* important and also that storage of old data is relatively cheap (the files are small and compress well).  Therefore, while all SCM tools of my acquaintance (many!) have ways to do this, it's typically (and intentionally) not easy to do.

## Conclusion

In conclusion, you have your choice of unpalatable options.  SCM tools such as subversion have assumptions about storage space and retention that can rapidly balloon storage requirements but file sync tools usually don't support the workflow most people would really like in their media library.

### When to use Subversion

If you don't mind doubling the disk space used on client devices and have a server with an additional 2x the disk space (room for expansion) and you expect to change your files fairly rarely (e.g. just change the MP3 tags or some such) then subversion might work well for you.

If you're pushing the limits on your storage space (SSD?) then "out of the box" subversion is probably not what you want though you might still be able to use it as part of your solution.